# unique vector with random numbers

Tags: c++, random

My program is to write a c++ program initializes an integer vector v of size SIZE with distinct random integers each in a range [0,2*SIZE], how can I ensure all of my numbers in the vector are unique
how can I edit my initialize vector so that it works properly, something in my logic is flawed. Shuffle cannot be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include<algorithm>

const int SIZE =10;
unsigned int seed = (unsigned)time(0);
using namespace std;

double random (unsigned int &seed);
void print_vector (vector<int> :: iterator b,
                   vector<int> :: iterator e );
void initialize_vector(vector<int> &v);
vector<int>v;

int main()
{
    cout << endl;
    initialize_vector(v);
    cout << "Vector : " << endl;
    print_vector(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}

double random(unsigned int &seed)
{
    const int MODULUS = 15749;
    const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
    const int INCREMENT = 1;
    seed = ((MULTIPLIER*seed)+INCREMENT)%MODULUS;
    return double (seed)/MODULUS;
}

void initialize_vector(vector<int> &v)
{
    vector<int> used;
    int count_unused, k;
    for (int i=0; i<2*SIZE; i++)
    {
        used.push_back(0);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        int j= (random(seed)*(2*SIZE+1-i)) + 1;
        count_unused = 0;
        k = 0;
        while (count_unused != j)
        {
            if (used[k] == 0)
                count_unused++;
            k++;
        }
        used[k] = 1;
        v.push_back(j);
    }

}

void print_vector (vector<int> :: iterator b,
                   vector<int> :: iterator e )
{
    vector<int> :: iterator p =b;
    while(p<e)
        cout << setw(3) << (*p++);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Since you said that you cannot use the `std::shuffle` algorithm. You can fill a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` randomly with values until their size is `SIZE` and then construct a vector with it. Its not the most efficient solution but it does the trick.

Comment: You should include restrictions or prohibitions (such as not allowed to shuffle) in the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) and [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)<sup>1</sup> do the trick:

```
constexpr int SIZE = 10;
std::vector<int> values(2*SIZE+1);
std::iota(begin(values), end(values), 0);
std::random_shuffle(begin(values), end(values));
values.resize(SIZE);
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0caca71a15fbd698

#### How it works?

First, a vector of `2*SIZE+1` is created...

```
std::vector<int> values(2*SIZE+1);
```

... and filled with consecutive integers from `0` to `2*SIZE`.

```
std::iota(begin(values), end(values), 0);
```

We shuffle those values...

```
std::random_shuffle(begin(values), end(values));
```

... and remove the second useless half.

```
values.resize(SIZE);
```

Voila.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Notice: this is a C++11/14 solution as `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated since C++14 and removed in c++17.

Comment: Beware that [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is deprecated since c++14 and removed in c++17. This doesn't work with the latest version of c++. You have to use `std::shuffle` instead.

Comment: i cant use the shuffle function

Comment: It has to be `std::vector<int> values(2*SIZE+1);` since the values have to be in [0, 2*SIZE]

Comment: @TAJINDERSUNDA then still you should follow that pattern, prepare a vector filled with numbers 0 till size*2, then random shuffle it, then pick the first `size` elements. If you reroll numbers until you get one that was not picked before, you wait till infinity in the worst case

Comment: @TAJINDERSUNDA implement it yourself ;)

Comment: Note: following the same (good) principle, if a loop is implemented instead of using `std::shuffle`, only `SIZE` random values have to be generated instead of `2*SIZE + 1` values.

Comment: @Damien it would be something what I proposed, Reservoir sampling, take a look at my answer

Comment: @YSC would be using shuffle under the different name/implementation considered as not using shuffle?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux No. note: my answer predates OP saying shuffle is not possible :)

Comment: @YSC ah, I see. Well, I have a better answer... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the solution without any storage and checks based on [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). We emulate stream with values from 0 to 2*SIZE inclusively, and fill reservoir with equal probabilities. No need to prefill and then erase data, one-pass sampling. NO SHUFFLE! Code, Visual C++ 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

constexpr int SIZE = 10;
constexpr int EOS = -1; // end-of-stream marker

static int s = 0;

void init_stream() {
    s = 0;
}

int next_stream() {
    if (s > 2 * SIZE)
        return EOS;
    return s++;
}

std::mt19937_64 rng{ 1792837ULL };

int random(int lo, int hi) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ud{ lo, hi };
    return ud(rng);
}

std::vector<int> reservoir(int size) {
    std::vector<int> r(size, 0);
    auto v = next_stream(); // value from stream
    for (int k = 0; v != EOS; ++k, v = next_stream()) {

        if (k < r.size()) { // fill reservoir
            r[k] = v;
        }
        else { // replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
            unsigned int idx = random(0, k);
            if (idx < r.size()) {
                r[idx] = v;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> h(2*SIZE+1, 0);

    for (int k = 0; k != 100000; ++k) {
        init_stream();
        std::vector<int> r{ reservoir(SIZE) };
        for (auto v : r) {
            h[v] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (auto v : h) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Printed histogram shows quite uniform distribution.

Comment: It is not what I was thinking (i.e. a simple adaptation of the previous solution with std::shuffle) but it is interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by sv90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399650/unique-vector-with-random-numbers#comment97520085_55399650) in the absence of `shuffle`, or with very large `SIZE`s you may prefer an `unordered_set` to ensure unique numbers. Initialize this `unordered_set` with a [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and then initialize your `vector` with this `unordered_set`. Something like this:

```
unordered_set<int> initialize_vector;
mt19937 g{ random_device{}() };
const uniform_int_distribution<int> random{ 0, SIZE };

while(size(initialize_vector) < SIZE) {
  initialize_vector.insert(random(g));
}

const vector<int> v{ cbegin(initialize_vector), cend(initialize_vector) };
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tOspxq)